# Neo4j database update command not working in recursive function(AutoCommit in Neo4j)

Tags: java, transactions, neo4j

I am trying to update my neo4j Graph database with a query.

```
int recursiveFunction()
{
     try(Transaction tx1 = graphDb.beginTx();)
     {
     int val=recursiveFunction()
     if(val==0)
     {
                    try(Transaction tx1 = graphDb.beginTx();)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Competed node "+applicationName);
                        String updateQuery="    match(p:Problem) where p.value=\""+applicationName+"\"  set p.completed=1  return p";   
                        ExecutionResult updateExecResult = execEngine2.execute(updateQuery);
                        System.out.println("Updated complete flag for "+applicationName);
                        System.out.println("new value of updated is + "+updateExecResult.dumpToString());
                        tx1.success();
                        tx1.close();
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        System.out.println("error in query");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
     }
}
```

The value gets updated and it is been shown correctly when i do the results.dumpToString(). But when i continue again in the loop and come back again ,the value is not updated.Is it because i am doing the commit incorrectly.My issue is even if the value is getting updated inside the recursive function after that the changes are not getting reflected.Is there a way of AUTOCOMMIT in neo4j.

Answer (score 0):

**Your code will never even compile.**

You should not name your transaction variables the same, the inner `tx1` shadows the outer tx1

And the construct try () {} already does a close automatically, so you close your inner tx **twice**.

And your outer tx get's never committed, because you never call `tx1.success()` on it.

The inner transactions, don't actually commit, they are just placebo transactions, which make sure you can nest functions.

You function also never aborts, because you can it indefinitely.

```
int recursiveFunction() {
    try(Transaction tx1 = graphDb.beginTx()) {
       // todo abort-condition
       int val=recursiveFunction()
       if(val==0) {
          try(Transaction tx2 = graphDb.beginTx()) {
            String updateQuery="    match(p:Problem) where p.value=\""+applicationName+"\"  set p.completed=1  return p";   
            ExecutionResult updateExecResult = execEngine2.execute(updateQuery);
            tx2.success();
          } catch(Exception e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
          }
       }
       tx1.success();
    } catch(Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: It is still the same.Because each time its going inside the recursive function,whatever it is doing in the inner recursive function will not reflect the outer recursive function.

Comment: I solved this by moving the transaction out of the recursive function.